# How to set Segment in UISegmentControl programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm setting UISegmentControl programmatically in my iPhone app. By default it has 2 segment. In my code I'm populating more than two segments. How do I set this, any help?

**Update**

My question is how do I put more than 2 tabs on segmentController by code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all segmented control in iOS is of UISegmentedControl class, not NS...

To create it with any number of segments you want you can use `initWithItems:` initialize method - pass array of titles (NSStrings) or images for each segments. e.g.:

```
UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil]];
```

Later you can change you control using `insertSegmentWithImage:atIndex:animated:`, `insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:` or/and `removeSegmentAtIndex:animated:` methods.

You can find descriptions on those (and some more!) methods in [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Comment: you can use insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated: method, no?

Comment: How do I add the array to SegmentWithTitle method?

Comment: @HardCode, you can't do that directly. Just add segments from array one by one in a loop

Answer (score 3):

Before your edit, you were actually talking about UISegmentedControl and to set the selected one programatically, you want to use the [`selectedSegmentIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/) property (the documentation for which I've linked for you).

And to add in additional segments, you can use [`insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/insertSegmentWithTitle%3aatIndex%3aanimated%3a).